# Photon 2 Can´t join random room

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I´m new to Networking and can´t find the problem on my self.
I made a matchmaking system for my game and it worked well.
But after some changes in my Game it stopped working.

It should create a room if no room is there. Else join a random room.
But it always creates a new room. no errors etc.

here are the scripts that should do the work.

Edit:

broke it down to this script:

```
using Photon.Pun;
using Photon.Realtime;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PhotonLobby2 : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
    public static PhotonLobby2 lobby;


    public GameObject battlebutton;

    private void Awake()
    {
        lobby = this;               // create singleton
    }

    void Start()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings();
    }

    public override void OnConnectedToMaster()
    {
        Debug.Log("connected to masterserver");
        PhotonNetwork.AutomaticallySyncScene = true;
        battlebutton.SetActive(true);
    }

    public void OnBattleButtonClicked()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.JoinRandomRoom();
    }

    public override void OnJoinRandomFailed(short returnCode, string message)
    {
        Debug.Log(message + returnCode);
        Debug.Log(" failed to join random game");
        CreateRoom();
    }

    void CreateRoom()
    {

        PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom("Room");

    }

    public override void OnCreatedRoom()
    {
        Debug.Log("Created Room");
        base.OnCreatedRoom();
    }

    public override void OnPlayerEnteredRoom(Player newPlayer)
    {
        Debug.Log("Entered");
        base.OnPlayerEnteredRoom(newPlayer);
    }
}
```

Debug says: No match found32760

Comment: Try to narrow down the issue by debugging. Also I suggest to use a versioning system like Git if you want to track back your changes and possibly revert to a working codebase.

Comment: had now setup a complete new scene with just the lobby script. debug says that no room was found. also made changes back and still dont work

Comment: I would slim down your example to show only where the problem is, along with the right context. Please see [mcve]

Comment: that´s the point. i don´t know where the problem is. connecting to master works. creating room too. just finding an existing not

Comment: Edited the post.

Comment: Hi @JamesBlond You should have more in the logs. "No match found32760" is the result of `Debug.Log(message + returnCode);`. You should also see " failed to join random game" and "Created Room". I think it's not OK to call `CreateRoom` from `OnCreateRoomFailed`. It's like an infinite loop since you are trying to create a room with the same name.

Comment: Creating a room ist not the Problem. Just a codefrag... The logs "Created Room" and " failed to Join random Game" Show Up too. Had Just posted the Things that matter.

Answer (score 2):

It is because the two players join matches in different regions... you can force this in the photon server settings **Fill in Dev region and Fixed region with one particular server region** that has better ping for you. Make the property Use sure name serve is also checked

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by checking the room properties which first player creates.
There is a variable of Room named "IsOpen". If it is false then second player cannot join the same room. I just set it to true and now its perfectly joining the same room.